# The go sort.Slice() sorting result does not meet the expectation

Tags: sorting, go

```
func main() {
    m := []int{1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0}
    rank := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    sort.Slice(rank, func(i, j int) bool {
        return m[i] > m[j]
    })
    fmt.Println(rank)
}

Return value:
[1 0 2 3 4 5]
Expected return value:
[1 2 0 3 4 5]
```

I tried to sort the values in the slice rank in descending order of slice m, but the result was not as expected. Is this a bug in the go sort package?

Comment: Possible [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). What is your actual problem? The code you showed us in your question doesn't make any sense; i.e., would never be used in production code. The two answers explain why you don't get the result you expected. What I am wondering is why you expected your example to produce your expected result since the values in `m` are never swapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Trock has provided a good example of how to do what your would like so I'll only examine why your code didn't work.

The result you have is a direct result of what the sorting function returns when it processes over the m array using the values of the rank array.

For the m[i] > m[j] the following results are returned:

m[1]=3 > m[0]=1 -> true

m[2]=2 > m[1]=3 -> false

m[3]=1 > m[2]=2 -> false

m[4]=0 > m[3]=1 -> false

m[5]=0 > m[4]=0 -> false

Given m is [1 3 2 1 0 0] this is correct

Now give rank is [0 1 2 3 4 5] the result of sorting according to that sequence of comparisons will result in [1 0 2 3 4 5] with only the first pair swapped as it is the only case where the comparison returned true indicating a swap was required.

Inserting a few debugging print statements into the code often helps highlight what is happening. Try adding one into the sort comparison function :-)

Answer (score 5):

The sort fails because [sort.Slice](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#Slice) swaps the elements of `rank`, but not the elements of `m`.
Use the [sort interface](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#Interface) and the [Sort](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#Sort) function to swap elements of `rank` and `m`.

Implement a type that satisfies the interface:

```
type rankm struct{ m, rank []int }
func (s rankm) Less(i, j int) bool { return s.m[i] > s.m[j] }
func (s rankm) Len() int           { return len(s.m) }
func (s rankm) Swap(i, j int) {
    s.m[i], s.m[j] = s.m[j], s.m[i]
    s.rank[i], s.rank[j] = s.rank[j], s.rank[i]
}
```

Sort like this:

```
m := []int{1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0}
rank := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
sort.Sort(rankm{rank: rank, m: m})
```

https://go.dev/play/p/mazWKPC4JRU

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `rank` has the values `0` ... `len(m) - 1` and you want to sort `rank` by `m[rank[i]]`, then use this code:

```
m := []int{1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0}
rank := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
sort.Slice(rank, func(i, j int) bool {
    return m[rank[i]] > m[rank[j]]
})
```

https://go.dev/play/p/OhOXaawJ1vS

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you don't need to worry about errors in the standard library. With good testing and a lot of developer attention, the probability of standard library errors is very low.

In your code, the `m` and `rank` are not a whole. You can not sort `m` by `rank`. Below is an example：

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {

    m := []int{1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0}

    rank := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

    // Create a type to bind m and rank together
    type Rank struct {
        m, rank int
    }

    rs := make([]Rank, len(m))

    for i := range m {
        rs[i] = Rank{m: m[i], rank: rank[i]}
    }

    // Sort by m value
    sort.Slice(rs, func(i, j int) bool {
        return rs[i].m > rs[j].m
    })

    // Extract sorted rank values
    sortedRank := make([]int, len(rank))
    for i, r := range rs {
        sortedRank[i] = r.rank
    }

    fmt.Println(sortedRank) // [1 2 0 3 4 5]

}
```